# how to pass a javascript associative array to php file using getJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hello I am working on a phonegap aplication and found on the internet a way to pass data to a php file using `$.getJSON()` the thing is that I got a Dictionary in on javascript

```
var info =[];
 if(document.getElementById(temp).checked){
          info[temp]="0";
        }
        else{
          info[temp]="1";
        } 
      }
```

So once the dictionary is created I want to send it to a external php file.

```
var archivoValidacion = "http://mysite.com/prueba.php?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON( archivoValidacion, {id_array:JSON.stringify(info)})
    .done(function(respuestaServer){
      alert(respuestaServer.validacion)});
```

and here is the php I got

```
<?php
$resultados = array();
$id_array = $_GET['id_array'];
$resultados["validacion"] = $id_array;
$resultadosJson = json_encode($resultados);


echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';

?>
```

The Problem is that I get a empty brackets when the pop up comes `[]`

Also when I have a normal array and send it I could print out every single array element on the php so this method works for me

thanks in advice

Comment: why you want to pass `{id_array:JSON.stringify(info)` via json just use `'id_array' : info` you can additionaly add urlencoding to it but json is not essensial

Comment: json supports no associative arrays but objects so try info = {}; and info.temp = "1";

Comment: What is being returned from the server?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is jsonp (JSON with padding) ... try this for your js file

```
var archivoValidacion = "http://mysite.com/prueba.php";
$.ajax({
    dataType:"jsonp",
    url:archivoValidacion,
    "data": {id_array:JSON.stringify(info)},
    "success": function(respuestaServer){
        alert(respuestaServer.validacion)
 }});
```

also on the php side you will have to change

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';
```

to

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';
```

Comment: this doesnt work and the output is an empty []:  `var info = [];
    info["test"] = "1";
 alert(JSON.stringify(info));`

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you are doing with your callback but i think you should try it like this:

info should be an object not an array

```
var info ={};
if(document.getElementById(temp).checked){
     info[temp]="0";
} else{
     info[temp]="1";
}
```

you dont need to JSON.stringify

```
var url= "http://mysite.com/prueba.php";
$.getJSON( url, {"id_array":info})
.done(function(data){
    alert(data.validacion);
});
```

if you call prueba.php with getJSON then you should return a json string, the callback is the function defined in .done():

```
<?php
$r = array();
// print_r($_GET); exit; // Maybe do a print_r and stop here to see what you got in firebug
$id_array = $_GET['id_array'];
$r["validacion"] = $id_array;
echo json_encode($r);   // See what your result look like in firebug console tab 
?>
```

Comment: I get this Error on my chrome console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl/prueba.php?&id_array%5Bp1c1%5D=1&id_array%5Bp1c2…5Bp2c2%5D=1&id_array%5Bp2c3%5D=1&id_array%5Bp2c4%5D=1&id_array%5Bp2c5%5D=1. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. `

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a few things:

JSON not support associative arrays, so you need change `var info = [];` to `var info = {};` and to assign a value you need to do `info.temp = "0"`

Don't use JSON.stringfy, because the response from your php script is something like this

```
{"validacion":"{\"temp\":\"0\"}"}
```

When you fire `alert(respuestaServer.validacion)` you will have [object Object]. Is better access to json member: `alert(respuestaServer.validacion.temp)`

Then, the fixed code is

```
var info ={};
if(document.getElementById(temp).checked){
    info.temp="0";
}
else{
    info.temp="1";
} 

...

var archivoValidacion = "http://mysite.com/prueba.php?jsoncallback=?";
$.getJSON( archivoValidacion, {id_array:info})
.done(function(respuestaServer){
    alert(respuestaServer.validacion.temp)
});
```

Comment: I always got the 1 because it only asaing to a variable temp
chrome console: `Object
cg1: undefined
cg2: undefined
temp: "1"`